# Is .__iter__() same as iter() in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

When I learn Dataloader in pytorch, I find an interesting thing related to iterator which puzzles me.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [1,2,3,4]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.l

cls_a = a()

# 1.
for c in cls_a.__iter__():
    print(c)

# 2.
for c in iter(cls_a):
    print(c)
```

Code #2 shows error: `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'`
while Code #1 works properly.

Then I do a second try:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]

# 3.
for c in l.__iter__():
    print(c)

# 4.
for c in iter(l):
    print(c)
```

Now Code #3 and #4 both work perfectly...

I know that what "for" loop does here is first using `iter(xxx)` to get an iterator, and then `next(iter(xxx))` to get the value. But when I try `iter(cls_a)`, should it be totally same as `iter([1,2,3,4])`?
So could you please let me know how it goes and the difference between using `a.__iter__()` and `iter(a)`?

Comment: If it helps, the for-loop isn't required to reproduce the error; `iter(cls_a)` on its own will error.

Comment: @wjandrea, yes I notice that, only iter(cls_a) will throw me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine that `iter` (ignoring its two-argument form) is defined as

```
def iter(x):
    return x.__iter__()
```

`x.__iter__` is, by definition, how you define what `iter(x)` *means*.

However, `iter` is expected to return an *iterator*, and `list` is not an iterator. It is an *iterable*. (I.e., the return value of `__iter__` is expected to have a `__next__` method, and `list.__next__` is not defined. `list.__iter__` returns an instance—in CPython, anyway—of `list_iterator`.)

A `for` loop always (implicitly) calls `iter` on the iterable you want to iterate over, so that

```
for l in x:
    ...
```

and

```
for l in iter(x):
    ...
```

behave identically for properly defined iterable and iterator classes. (Iterators are generally expected to define a trivial `__iter__ = lambda x: x` method to make them iterable as well.)

Because `__iter__` is, in some sense, an *implemenation* detail of the iterator protocol, it is better to call `iter` instead of `__iter__` directly. Like most magic methods, `__iter__` usually should be called only if you are subclassing an iterator and need to use `super().__iter__` in the definition of the overriden `__iter__` method.

---

Of course, it can't be as simple as that. Still ignoring the two-argument form of `iter`, Python can provide a "default" iterator defined in terms of `__len__` and `__getitem__` if `__iter__` isn't defined. So a more complicated version of `iter` might be

```
def iter(x):
    try:
        i = x.__iter__
    except AttributeError:
        return (x[n] for n in range(len(x)))

    return i()
```

If necessary, you iterate over `x` by simply calling `x.__getitem__` repeatedly for as long as `x.__len__` allows.

---

Not really on-topic, but since I've twice alluded to a two-argument form of `iter`, I may as well show how that fits in.

```
_x = object()
def iter(itr_or_func, sentinel=x):
    if sentinel is _x:
        try:
            i = itr_or_func.__iter
        except AttributeError:
            return (itr_or_func[n] for n in range(len(itr_or_func)))
    else:
        while True:
            rv = itr_or_func()
            if rv == sentinel:
                break
            yield rv
```

Comment: While mostly correct, this answer could be more precise: I can define a class `A` such that `assert not hasattr(A, '__iter__')` and `assert list(iter(A())) == list(range(6))` both pass.

Comment: True, there is still the old-style way of implementing the iterator protocol by defining `__len__` and `__getitem__`, which Python can use to implement a "default" iterator like `(x[i] for i in range(0, len(x)))`.

Comment: Your `iter` definition is missing the aspect in question, checking whether the result is an iterator.

Comment: It uses `while`, not `for`: `__len__` is not mandatory as well and is not used as actual iteration limit. `__len__` is used only to provide `__length_hint__` on the iterator.

Comment: Oh, right. What does it actually do, call `__getitem__` until an `IndexError` is raised?

Comment: Yeah, it's like `for i in itertools.count(0)`: `try: yield gen[i]; except (IndexError, StopIteration): return`, using `__len__` and a bit of magic to make e.g. `list(iter(A()))` memory efficient, if possible. (Catching `StopIteration` to make it clear that raising `StopIteration`, while unconventional, will break the iteration - in fact it most probably catches `IndexError` only and re-raises `StopIteration` instead)

Comment: With your `iter` definition and statement that *"iter is expected to return an iterator, and list is not an iterator"*... Are you thinking that `iter` returns a list? It doesn't.

Comment: The OP is returning a list from `a.__iter__`.

Comment: I know. What's your point?

Comment: My point is, I'm telling the OP that a `list` is not a valid return value for `__iter__`.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were responding to me (and my comments pointing out that you wrongly make it look like `iter` returns that list).

Comment: @chepner though I am not very clear about every word you guys communicated, I know something. So the main point here is that iter() will not only get what __iter__() returns, but also checking whether the return is an iterator (use __iter__() directly will not do the 2nd part). Like wjandrea said, just writing iter(cls_a)  will raise error. Iter([1,2,3,4]) will return the list_iterator so it can pass the check.

Comment: @chepner I have a small question then, if the x is already an iterator, iter(x) will directly return x, right? If not, the will be an iterator of an iterator which is clearly wrong. Actually, I tried iter(iter([1,2,3,4]))  and for i in iter([1,2,3,4]), both fine so I assume that.

Comment: If you write `for x in foo: ...`, for example, Python doesn't even look to see if `foo.__next__` is defined: it will call `iter(foo)` to get something with a `__next__` method. If `foo.__iter__` doesn't return `foo`, then the loop may not behave the way you would expect, knowing that `foo.__next__` is defined.